# distribution in a sample Probability theory

Tags: probability

So i am not sure about the effect the sample has on a distribution;

the exercise is the following:
The probability that the phone is defective is 0.03. Compute the probability that a sample of 500 phones will contain 2 or more defective.

I think if X is the probability that the phone is defective,distribution is the following:
P(X=x)=(97/100)^(k-1) * (3/100) for k 1,2,3... But i am not sure how the sample of 500 influence this distribution and if i should change it in order to calculate exercise based of sample amount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of the binomial distribution - given a flat probability of a failure (in your case $3\%$) per trial, the distribution is the number of failures we see for a set of $n$ trials (in your case 500).

The easier way to do this is to find the probability of observing $1$ or fewer failures and then subtracting that from $1$

So the probability for a binomial distribution of observing $k$ failures  in $n$ trials is ${n\choose k}\cdot p^k\cdot (1-p)^{n-k}$. We want $1-P(1 failure)-P(0 failures)$.

So that comes out to
$1-{500 \choose 0}\cdot 0.03^0\cdot .97^{500}-{500 \choose 1}\cdot 0.03^1\cdot .97^{499}\approx .999996$